# What is the tagline for our site, what's our sales pitch?

Tags: discussion

[5.What’s the “elevator pitch” for our site?](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/)

This is not quite the same as [How do we promote our site?](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52/how-do-we-promote-our-site).

This is what is the essence of our site? What can we provide that makes us different to other sites or blogs offering advice or information about pets?

How is our format unique and different, perhaps better than forums, blogs, or sponsored sites?

Comment: Answering questions like this is why I'm not in advertising... :D

Comment: We should progress on this. There are a few pro trainers in my area that I would like to attract here, but I don't feel like I can write a good tagline..

Answer (score 4):

I think the fact that we are focused on questions and answers and aren't just a general forum is one selling point - it creates a much better signal to noise ratio than a lot of other places online where the freedom to post anything as a response can make it difficult to source actual practical information.

Also, we aren't centered on any one species. A lot of blogs and sites have a specific focus (cats, dogs, lizards, what have you), whereas anyone with any pet can come in here and likely get a really good answer to their problem.

Another good thing, I think, is our lack of sponsorship - sites that are sponsored by, say, a particular food manufacturer or the like is likely to be pretty biased and will generally recommend their products as often as possible, whereas we won't have anything like that here.

Comment: `I think the fact that we are focused on questions and answers and aren't just a general forum` Yes, plus any other SE-specific benefits, like reputation.

Comment: `Also, we aren't centered on any one species.` **but** questions are tagged so if people want to view only questions/answers about one species it's easy to search for.

Answer (score 0):

The Tagline is pretty simple I think.

- "You have a question about your pet, we have someone who can answer it, let's make things happen"

  or
- "Better than your vet (because it's free*)"

  <sup>*ISP Rates not included.</sup>

---

If we want a Motto, I think it should be "We like turtles". But for people who don't like turtles (no one), and since Animal Planet took the good one, we could use:

- "Where the domesticated things are"
- "Pet Owner Co. Where the Pet Owners Go"
- "Happy Pets = Happy Owners"
- "The best friend of your best friend"
- "Education you won't find in a school"

---

In all seriousness, Ashley has it right. We are the place you go to if you need to find an answer quickly, and need to know how that answer stands with an entire community of pet owners. Our voting system allows for our answers to be peer-reviewed. Showing you how many people agree with that answer as the correct one.

And that we do this out of the goodness of our hearts, not because Santa is watching, or a company is paying us (hopefully). If we recommend a product to you, it's because we used it, and we found it to work. And again, if I say something works, you can see how many people agree with me that it works.

Comment: Those last two paragraphs are the tag-line. Well past the desired length of max five words, of course ;)

Comment: "Pets - the other white meat."