# Who should we invite to the private beta?

Tags: discussion, beta, new-users

While we have a thread for [How do we promote our site](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52/how-do-we-promote-our-site), we have the ability to invite others to the private beta to help create questions, etc.

This is a more intimate time where we need to set examples for what the questions will be going forward, but we should consider asking others to come help out.

What I'd like to see as answers to this question here are:

1) a proper paragraph to introduce this site AS A BETA to someone who could help us create the core / basis (you'd assume these people might have been contacted to support the Area 51 proposal, but I think that takes a different mindset).

2) suggestions as to who to invite.

Taking a note from the "promote" thread, I think inviting some select volunteer groups to help out at this time and ask proper questions (assuming you are familiar enough with them) would be a good idea.  I plan to invite two dachshund volunteer groups I've adopted from in the past to the private beta.  As noted, I'll wait till I have a couple answers (or a nicely edited / peer-reviewed answer) to (1) above before I do so.

Comment: Well then, I've invited a dog trainer and a vet technician.  Don't know if they'll participate, but we'll see.

Answer (score 3):

The private beta should only last two weeks. We're getting plenty of questions as is. In fact, our [Area 51 page](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/44686/pets) shows we have over 80 questions a day where 15 is considered healthy.

I don't know how you invite people to the private beta, but it's main reason for being private is to make sure that people already committed to the site create an initial body of questions, so that when the site emerges into public beta it's not just an empty shell. It helps not only attract people but also to make them stick around.

So I'd suggest holding off until we are in public beta to promote the site to interested groups. That way, we hopefully get more of them to stick around and really get them interested in the site.

Comment: *"I don't know how you invite people to the private beta"*  - Invitation is the "Invite Fellow Experts" box on the right when you go to the main pets.SE.com page.