# Let's discuss some ideas for promotional flyers!

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

[Parenting has flyers](https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257/did-you-know-that-we-have-flyers) for promotion.  I'm not saying we need to use the same media resource they did (Jin) as he might be backed up, but we can help by

1. Nominating / Selecting 5-6 good, solid (to-the-point) *answered* questions.
2. Deciding on some imagery to use.
3. Determining where to place them.

Per [Ashley Nunn's Answer](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52/how-do-we-promote-our-site), these flyers would be put on bulletin boards at pet shops, including stores which are likely specific to fish and reptiles, therefore the questions should run the gamut.  I'd recommend suggesting at least one dog, cat, reptile, and fish question.

I've more than a moderate amount of graphic design, so I'd be willing to throw something together based on the question asked.  I'm not a QR-Code aficionado, but I'm fairly certain you just throw a short URL into a generator to crank one out, so I'm 100% unconcerned with that aspect of the flyer.

Let's hear some suggestions!

Viable answers (oh forbid, SE list answers!) can include:

1. A list of potential questions to use
2. A list of places where we can put up the flyers
3. Submitted designs or imagery based on questions you like

Comment: I like it... I'm sure our vet would be happy to post something like this too. I would happily print them out for that. QR Code is easy to generate, plenty of places to do it.

Comment: Hmm, perhaps our pets themselves might become the best evangelists the site could possibly have :) Who can resist ceiling cat's cousin telling folks to check the place out - this is a chance to get _really_ creative and flex those photography muscles :)

Comment: Have few ideas but don't have drawing skills and don't even want to break any copy-write law by using random images from net.

Comment: @AnkitSharma - You won't break laws by posting images here from around the net, as long as those images don't make it into the final product; they can be used to help solidify ideas.  Alternately, you can just describe what you want to try to achieve.

Comment: @TimPost - good to see you're OK.  Photos can work.  We can either try here, or I can set up a Flyers Chat.

Comment: @JoshDM I don't see why both (here and perhaps a chat room) would need to be mutually exclusive - so long as any great ideas in chat eventually found their way here, might be nice for folks to talk about it in real time. That said, I'm sure this is of interest to the main room, do you think a separate one is needed?

Comment: I hate flooding the main room with images.

Comment: The main room, for the most part, seems to like images.

Answer (score 3):

Few ideas came to my mind are from my own two question which looks popular to me.

[How can I manage excessive hair shedding from dogs?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/174/how-can-i-manage-excessive-hair-shedding-from-dogs)

[image]

or

[How can I train a dog to not misbehave with a cat?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/483/how-can-i-train-a-dog-to-not-misbehave-with-a-cat)

[image]

Both images are for explanation purpose and even second one might be offensive for a flyers. But my opinion is to select question which are basic question, which comes to pet-keepers mind in general or day to day generic problem.

The appropriate SE site to post this Flyers appears to me are [biology](https://biology.stackexchange.com/), [cogsci](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/), [parenting](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/) and [sustainability](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/). Because Animals (Pets) are big part of Biological studies. Few question even being related to parenting here. And animal is also a part of psychological studies and psychiatric help and even a part of a lifestyle.

***Note***:- Images are for understating purpose as we don't own their usage rights.

Comment: You and I have very different definitions of "offensive".  That second one looks like it was taken out of context and was possibly snapped mid-play.

Comment: @JoshDM few pet-keepers are very sensitive, so tried to avoid  hurting someone's emotion.

Comment: The shedding one is great, though!  I have no reference material; my dogs are short-hair.

Comment: @JoshDM  hair shedding is very common problem among Labrador/shaggy/golden retriever owners. And can be serve as a generic question.

Comment: Also, with the images, we want to make sure we aren't taking them from somewhere that doesn't actually allow us to use them

Comment: @AshleyNunn - As mentioned in the comments on the question post itself, we won't be using any external, non-user-owned images except to demonstrate concepts.

Comment: @AshleyNunn i am not a good drawer, so can't draw my ideas. So images used are just for Ideas.